# logstash custom patterns don´t get resolved

Tags: logstash, logstash-grok

I´m trying to setup an environment for grok debugging and made this with a docker.

Everything works fine, until logstash tries to resolve a custom pattern.
Here is my environment

I start the docker with

> docker run -it --name logstash_debug -v
>   /home/cloud/docker-elk/logstash/config/logstash.yml:/usr/share/logstash/config/logstash.yml
>   -v /home/cloud/docker-elk/logstash/pipeline/:/usr/share/logstash/pipeline/
>   -v /home/cloud/docker-elk/logstash/patterns/:/usr/share/logstash/patterns
>   docker.elastic.co/logstash/logstash:7.2.0

As I said, logstash starts up, loads the pipeline (debug.conf)

```
input { stdin {} } 

filter {  
    grok {
          patterns_dir => ["/usr/share/logstash/patterns"]
          match => ["message", "%{YEAR1} \[%{LOGLEVEL:loglvl}\] %{GREEDYDATA:message}"]
    } 
    date {
        match => ["customer_time", "${YEAR1}"]
        target =>  "@timestamp"
    }
}

output { stdout { codec => rubydebug } }
```

and gives me this error:

> Cannot evaluate `${YEAR1}`. Replacement variable `YEAR1` is not
>   defined in a Logstash secret store or as an Environment entry and
>   there is no default value given.

the patterns_dir contains a file "dateformats" which contains (stripped it down to a minimum)

> YEAR1 %{YEAR}

the logstash debug output gives me this:

> [DEBUG][logstash.filters.grok    ] config
>   LogStash::Filters::Grok/@patterns_dir =
>   ["/usr/share/logstash/patterns"]
>
> [DEBUG][logstash.filters.grok    ] config
>   LogStash::Filters::Grok/@match = {"message"=>"%{YEAR1}
>   \[%{LOGLEVEL:loglvl}\] %{GREEDYDATA:message}"} 
>   .....
>
> [DEBUG][logstash.filters.grok    ] config
>   LogStash::Filters::Grok/@patterns_files_glob = "*"

Normally logstash should be able to grab this file (I even started the docker with --user 0 to be sure that I have no permission problem) but it somehow can´t.

Anyone can me give a hint to what´s going on ?

Thanks and cheers,

Wurzelseppi

Comment: You can't use `${YEAR1}` in the date plugin.

Comment: OMG .... out of habit I used ${...} .... what a du%§%$  I am.....
Thanks man!